# Passing data between fragment in tabhost

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabhost

i create a tabhost with two fragment

```
 mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost)rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost1);
    mTabHost.setup(getActivity(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.id.tabcontent1);

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentb").setIndicator("STATIONS"), Ligne11Tram.class, null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("fragmentc").setIndicator("INFO TRAFIC"), Infotrafictram.class, null);
```

I want to send data from the first fragment(Ligne11Tram) to the 2nd fragment (Infotrafic) , 
please can someone tell me how to do

Answer (score 1):

Well with passing info between fragments on the same activity, the easiest method is likely calling a function in the acitivity from the 1st and passing info into the second.

Kind of like on the first fragment.

```
((ActivityClass) getActivity()).functonWithVaraiblesToPassToSecond(variables);
```

In the activity class:

```
public void functonWithVaraiblesToPassToSecond(variables) {
     secondFragment.funcitonToAcceptVariables(varaibles);
}
```